# Bypass Login if a specific URL is visited

Tags: users

I am into a strange fix with my site.

Firstly, my site is password protected. So, when I visit, http://www.example.com it is greeted with a nice shiny login page. User puts in the credentials and goes in.

Now, I am hoping that for some special people, they don't have to login. For that I need to have some specific URL, say, http://www.example.com/bypass which takes me to the site without any login page.

Is it possible?

Comment: what user should the users that goto http://www.example.com/bypass get?  the same one regardless of how many people visit? or unique/different users?

Comment: Hi, they'll all have the anonymous role.

Comment: They will all have the anonymous role by default without even doing anything special....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no coding, you might be able to use this module: https://drupal.org/project/rolereferral

With coding:

Create a new user role that has all the same permissions as "Authenticated user".  Call it "bypass", for example.

Create a unique page, or a menu hook,  that adds the new "bypass" role to the current PHP $user object.

Comment: Role Referral is till Drupal 6 :(. Anyway you could help a little with the code way you mentioned?